# Selected menu is never active in jQuery plugin by mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a jQuery menu plugin from http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

Everything is working fine, but when I select the sub menu, it never shows the active state. It keeps on sending to the main page after page loads. See the screenshot for more information.

[image: sub-menu]

[image: keep on sending to the main menu]

I am doing this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="listview-icons">
        <li>
            <a>
                <form method="post" action="{$site_url}/tracking.html" name="trak_now_homepage" id="trak_now_homepage">
                    <div class="form-group texttransform">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shipment_track_num" name="track_num" placeholder="Enter the booking ID">
                        <span id="shipment_alert" class="alert" style="color:#CF0"></span>
                        <BR />
                        <input name="news_go" type="submit" value="Track now" class="com_buton" id="send" onclick="return valid_shipment_tracking_form(document.trak_now_homepage);" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="{$site_url}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> &nbsp; HOME</a></li>
        <li>
            <span><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> &nbsp; SEND</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/send_document.html"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> &nbsp;DOCUMENTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span><i class="fa fa-plane"></i> &nbsp; SERVICES</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/sameday.html"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> &nbsp;SAME DAY DELIVERY</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp; ABOUT US</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/about_us.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp; ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/faq.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp;FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/how.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp;HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/advice.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp;PACKAGING ADVICE</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/reviews.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp;REVIEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/terms.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp; TERMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/policy.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp; POLICIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$site_url}/volume_calculator.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp; VOLUME CALCULATOR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="{$site_url}/contact_us.html"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> &nbsp;CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="{$site_url}/my_cart_details.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i>ITEMS</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="{$site_url}/my_account.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> my account</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to fix this? The working demo is at [www.matchcouriers.com](http://www.matchcouriers.com)

Comment: can you provide a working demo that shows your problem?

Comment: seems to be working fine on my end but the menu does not match with the one you've provided in screenshot. edit: hm ok, it's responsive.

Comment: @OzgurBar help me to fix this. as you can seen see selected states never shown.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? The selected menu item should change color?

Comment: @alan0xd7 yeah there should be two things , first selected menu have a dark background and also sub-menu panel should stay as it is, but after selecting menu and page load, main-menu appear no the selected sub-menu panel

Comment: can you get rid of the `bootstrap-select.min.css` or `bootstrap-select.css`. both are included in script refs atm, it's causing a conflict. i'm receiving errors regarding this in console.

Comment: and reference to jquery.js must be placed before bootstrap also. i'm not sure if it's related to those but i'm still getting errors.

Comment: Maybe you can try relative URLs? That is, instead of `href="https://www.matchcouriers.com/about_us.html"`, just use `href="/about_us.html"`

Comment: @alan0xd7 menu's working fine in certain viewports, but it's not wroking fine in tablets or mobiles for instance.

Comment: I was thinking about the issue that sub-menus not matching the current page, maybe it could be that the script uses relative URL to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, using smarty condition as i am using smarty as a template and the class that need to be used from mmenu is mm-seleced

```
<li class="mm-selected"><a href="http://match.local"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> &nbsp; HOME</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default mmenu uses the css class `Selected` (note the capital S) on the current `li` for the current selected item.

> selected menu have a dark background

You must define your own `li.Selected` style, I don't think you have done this.

> sub-menu panel should stay as it is, but after selecting menu and page load, main-menu appear no the selected sub-menu panel

This is actually not automatic. You need to add `Selected` class to the relevant `li` on your pages. For example, in the About Us page, you would do this:

```
<li class="Selected"><a href="/about_us.html"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp; ABOUT US</a></li>
```

References:

- [Styling Lists](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorials/basic/styling-lists.html)
- [Menu Items not selected after page load](https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/312)